# Converting svg to json

Tags: json, svg, path, raphael

I want to be able to create a svg image in Illustrator and convert it to json to be able to use it with Raphael js, as below.

How could this be done without a server side script?

**What I want:**

```
[0,0,255.3,298.5,{type:'path',path:'M 35.3 257.2 C 34.4 245.7 45.4 234.1 48.5 223 C 53.6 204.3 55 185 60 166.2 C 69.5 131 69.6 97.1 89.1 65.1 C 103.4 41.7 129.5 5.3 161.3 19.7 C 184.6 30.3 181.3 59.2 188.9 78.9 C 207.5 127.3 228.6 184.8 230.3 237.3 C 231.3 268.6 202.8 261.3 178.2 264 C 149.2 267.1 120 269.6 91 272.2 C 84.2 272.8 75.8 274.2 69 273 C 60.9 271.6 28.9 259.9 31.3 249.2','fill':'#39b54a','stroke':'none','stroke-width':'0','fill-opacity':'1','stroke-opacity':'0'}];
```

Comment: Here's a solution using Python: https://github.com/gwintrob/svg-to-json I stumbled across this GitHub repo that uses JS, but it didn't support a large SVG file: https://github.com/chrisfinch/svg-to-json